# Share extension not showing up for my existing Universal project

Tags: objective-c, share-extension

I am adding a share extension to my existing Universal app, but it's never showing up in the shared menu.
xcode 9.3 , Deployment target for Parent app and extension 9.3

**Steps for adding xcode**

1. File -> New -> Target-> shareExtesnion
2. All certificates for share extension + containing app on automatic.
3. Enable app Groups for bot app and extension.
4. Select Same app group for app and extension.
5. Build the app using safari.

build successfull, and safari opens fine, but can't see my App extension on the share sheet.

Then created new sample app with same steps mention above, it works properly.

**Things I tried to clear the issue**

1. Created new App group.
2. Deployment target changed to 11.3
3. Changed ActivationRule

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
    </dict>
```

I need your valuable suggestions. Thanks in advance.